# Excel List to PowerPoint Slide Header

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have looked at a ton of questions that have already been posted but nothing quite fits what I am looking for. I have an excel list of ~ 750 different title/headers that I need to use to create PPT slides. I just need to create a titled but otherwise blank PPT slide. I am extremely new to coding and most of the solutions are more complicated that I need (i.e. importing charts and pictures). Any help to point a noob in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Save from Excel to a plain text file. You'll probably need to break this up into a couple of steps because PPT won't handle more than a certain number of these at a go.

Then start PowerPoint and choose File | Open, Files of type: *.*
Choose your text file and let PPT open it.

Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I was able to do this in 4 separate projects. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank ppt file - in the first slide paste in a single column table with your excel data, Ive assumed your required headers are in each row. Name the table (Ive used HeadersTable) - you can use the Selection Pane to do this found on the Home tab.

Open the VBA editor in ppt - Alt+F11, add a new module and run the below code.

```
Sub createHeaders()

    Dim sl As Slide
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long

    Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set tbl = sl.Shapes("HeadersTable").Table

    For i = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count

        Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(i + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
        Set shp = sl.Shapes("Title 1")
        shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = tbl.Rows(i).Cells.Item(1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: My poor work laptop can't handle the size of the file. I did a test run with a smaller file and it worked great. Thanks! I will keep this in my library so smaller projects until I get a more powerful computer :)